# numpy imports are working fine in pyspark shell but failing with architecture error (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64') in spark-submit in Mac M1 machine

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, apple-m1, arm64

I have installed pyspark using pip3 install pyspark and installed all the dependencies like great_expectations using pip3.

When I try to run the code using spark-submit it is failing with "/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))"

I checked the python interpreter, it is a universal binary.

```
...@ATL100000847245 bin % file $(which python3)
/usr/bin/python3: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/python3 (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/python3 (for architecture arm64e): Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

surprisingly when I run these imports in pyspark interactive shell they work fine without any issues.

Sample Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


logFile = "/Users/.../spark/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/README.md"  # Should be some file on your system
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SimpleApp").getOrCreate()
logData = spark.read.text(logFile).cache()

numAs = logData.filter(logData.value.contains('a')).count()
numBs = logData.filter(logData.value.contains('b')).count()

print("Lines with a: %i, lines with b: %i" % (numAs, numBs))

spark.stop()
```

Error Message I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Developer/Repos/night-eagle/platform/python/apps/purposing/sample.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 139, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.25.0"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```

Where as if I import numpy in pyspark shell it works fine.

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Mar 10 2023, 20:16:38) 
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/06/21 18:04:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.4.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.9.6 (default, Mar 10 2023 20:16:38)
Spark context Web UI available at http://a4efxml61027.eis.equifax.com:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1687385077853).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([12,23,23])
>>> print(a)
[12 23 23]
```

I tired installing X86_64 binary of numpy then spark-submit seems to be working fine but pyspark shell breaks.

Is there any solution to make it work in both pyspark shell and spark-submit.

Comment: I'm having the same issue now, but when using udf, have you managed to solve it?